# Process of the max of a gaussian process

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, extreme-value

I know how to calculate the distribution of the max of a Gaussian process.

I am now wondering what's its process. Are its properties known? (For instance I guess that the length of constant parts are distributed as the times of return to the origin for a Gaussian process).

I can hardly find literature by googling "Process of the max of a gaussian process" because I get "max of a gaussian process" results. Anyone knows the relevant equation/facts/literature?

Comment: Maybe [reflection principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle_(Wiener_process)) for the Wiener processes, $ \mathbb{P} \left(\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} W(s) \geq a \right) = 2\mathbb{P}(W(t) \geq a)$,  may be of help?

Comment: or even this paper: [Jean-Marc Azaïs, Li-Vang Lozada-Chang. A toolbox on the distribution of the maximum of Gaussian
process. 2013. ffhal-00784874f](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00784874/document)